# Upgrading from 100 to 200 amp load centre with 100 amp service shutoff

Tags: electrical

[image: enter image Main Panel]    [image: Fused SHutoff between main panel and meeter] [image: Meter] I want to upgrade my load centre panel that currently has a 100 amp main breaker w to 200 amp one along with the 100 amp service shutoff. The main is about 20' from the inside 100 amp fused shutoff connected with NMD-7 3/3. The meter base is outside on the opposing wall of the shutoff and is rated 200 amp.  The shutoff and meter base are connected via conduit so i can't easily see the wire gauge. 
Do i need to replace the NMD-7 3/3 wire?
Can i replace the main panel with a 200 amp and change the 100 amp service shutoff at a later date?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange.  I'm a little confused.  Are you saying the service shutoff is between the meter pan and the main panel (electrically)?  Does it have overcurrent protection at 100A?  Breaker or fuses?   I am also unclear on your endgame goal. Are you aiming to increase your usable electrical service to 200A, or just like 200A sized panels? (We do too :)

Comment: The breaker panel with 100 amp main is on an inside wall in the cottage due to an addition, It is protected on the other side of the room with a 100 amp fused shutoff which is connected via conduit the outside meter just behind it. The panel has 24 breakers and is full. no room for expansion, tight and a rats nest. I have some immediate plans to do some renovations and add a couple of 15 amp circuits bathroom/bedroom. I likely don't have to go to 200 amps but none of the  bedrooms have any heat source at this time.

Comment: If i every want to make it 4 season i'd likely put those in sometime in the future hence i am thinking of putting in a 200 amp panel. Maybe my best bet is to install a 200amp panel downgrade the main to 100 amps and hold on to the 200 for the future, Or can i just leave the 200 main breaker in the new panel for now knowing the 100 amp fused shutoff will protect an overload scenario -- is that allowed according to code. Hope that helps.

Comment: Where are you on this planet, and what is this NMD-7 cable you're seeing?

Comment: Wonderin' aboot his location, eh?

Comment: @Harper Is that Federal Pioneer shuttoff a problem? I've seen one before, and I'm pretty sure it uses 100A fuses on each leg, so I'm not sure if that suffers from the same problems as a FPE panel in the US.

Comment: @HariGanti No idea.  I made my comment before he posted any of those pictures or added the detail.   I'm not *enough* of an expert on old service equipment to say for sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a 200 A panel with 100 A service with no problem; it's done quite regularly. You can just put a 100 A main breaker on it (saving the 200 A one it may have come with for later). A lot of times the 200 A panels are cheaper, have more slots, and/or are just physically bigger (easier to work in), which is why they are used even if the service is less than 200 A.

Comment: Ontario, Canada

Comment: Ontario, Canada. The NDM-7 3/3 runs from the inside fused shutoff to the main load centre panel on the other side of the room.